# Swiss-style Monetary Policy

Tags: monetary-policy

I'm doing some research on investing and financial advisers. Not that I have a lot (no debt, less than 20K in net worth), but I've recently finished paying off all my student loans, and am now considering where I should put the extra 1K/month (savings vs. an existing mutual fund vs. somewhere else). To complicate matters, I'm closing in an a business plan, and hope to stop working full-time by the summer or fall to launch my business full time. But all of this is outside of the realm of my question.

As I was researching financial advisers, I came across 1 website locally that said the following: "We are a conservative, financial planning firm that uses a Swiss-style monetary policy to guide our investment style."

What in the world do they mean by "Swiss-style monetary policy"? I'm doing some googling, and will continue to do so throughout the day. I'm sure I'll come up with some answers on my own, but I'm curious to see what this community says about it.

Comment: Not being snarky, but if they cannot clearly explain their strategy to you in terms you can understand, then they aren't worth it.  Maybe that is a thing and maybe it isn't, but their job is to work for you, and explain it to you.  The whole point is to advise you, not make decisions for you.

Comment: What caught my eye was the different financial stages in one question: less then 20K net worth; just finished paying off student loans; 1K per month in extra income to invest; want to quit my job in a few months to start a business; yet I am looking for an investment company. If you will be quitting in a few months and will be living off your savings while getting a business started, why do you need an investment company?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what is called ["weasel words"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word). They're trying to put some authority into their ad, but since they don't have any - they're putting meaningless words that sound important.

[Monetary policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monetary_policy) is the state/central bank policy to control the supply of the available currency. Cannot think of a way to connect it to private investments.

Comment: Heh. Well said. I wasn't sure if they were saying "anything" or not!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is traditionally meant by "Swiss-style monetary policy" but lately it has meant the same thing as US monetary policy, or Japanese monetary policy, or Euro monetary policy: PRINT.

Look how many Swiss Francs it takes to buy a currency that cannot be printed:
[image]

I'm not sure why they would be touting "Swiss-style monetary policy".

That hasn't been too stellar lately.

Comment: CHARTS A GO-GO!!!  =)

Comment: -1 rant against monetary policy and a jab at fiat money in general isn't very topical to this question :P

Comment: You're failing to mention why the Swiss adopted their current monetary policy -- Swiss merchants were unable to function and prices were spiraling as international investors stocked up on Francs. People literally were driving to Germany for groceries.

Comment: @duff - The focus is always on producers and exporters when it comes to an appreciating currency.  What about the consumer who can now buy lots of stuff cheaply in other countries?  What about the merchant himself who can buy supplies cheaply in other countries?  Will all the merchants in Switzerland go out of business due to an appreciating currency?  If so, where will people in Switzerland get money to buy things?  They still have to produce goods to trade with other countries which is one of the main purposes of money - to exchange goods.

Comment: If the exchange rate would have persisted indefinitely, that would have been fine. But since it was mostly driven by capital inflows, it's unlikely that it would have persisted. So in the short-term people would adjust their habits, some businesses would fold and others would be created; but in the long-term they'd just have to undo it all again. Both sets of change would be disruptive and damaging.

Comment: @Ganesh - So currencies are the only item in a market environment that can not adjust in value or price?  Any other items you would like to exclude from the market price setting mechanism?  And why not let the swiss citizens use any currency so that they could switch to weaker currencies at any time if they thought that would help their situation.

Comment: Not that this has anything to do with the Swiss monetary policy, but your first graph shows how many CHF you get for a USD. It went from 1.8 to less than 1. Ouch… for those earning dollars, and needing to buy Swiss francs (CHF). In other words, during the last 10 years, the Swiss franc has become a considerably stronger currency than the US dollar.

Comment: @avernet - Thanks for the comment.  I removed the first graph.

Comment: @Muro - governments do intervene directly in other markets, e.g. oil (by building a strategic stockpile), and indirectly in other markets through regulation, e.g. utilities.